# React bootstrap modal es6

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Hello i need help displaying a bootstrap modal

```
 import React from 'react';
    import styles from '../App.css';
    import styles from '../../../public/css/app.css';

    import Button from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button';
    import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Modal';


    export default class Edit extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    console.log(props)

    this.state=  { showModal: false };

    this.state = {showModal:true};
    this.open = this.open.bind(this);
    this.close = this.close.bind(this);
    }


    close() {
      this.setState({ showModal: false });
    }

    open() {
      alert("open modal")
      this.setState({ showModal: true });
    }


    render() {

      return (
      <div>
        <p>Click to get the full Modal experience!</p>

        <Button
          bsStyle="primary"
          bsSize="large"
          onClick={this.open.bind(this)}
        >
          Launch demo modal
        </Button>

        <Modal show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.close}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <h4>Text in a modal</h4>
            <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula.</p>

            <hr />

            <h4>Overflowing text to show scroll behavior </h4>
            <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={this.close}>Close</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      </div>

    );
  }
  }
```

The modal is not showing any suggestions?

I followed and the react bootstrap document and babel es6 recommendation.

Comment: Any error message? Because you set `ture` to Modal like `<Modal show={true} onHide={this.close}>`, the modal will show at first. Does it works? Show at first?

Comment: No error message i fixed it to how it was at the docs

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this except for your double declaration of styles at the top. You should change their names so they don't conflict. I know that you are using this exactly from the react-bootstrap docs but have you confirmed that when your component is rendered, this.state.showModal is true?

Comment: thank you very much guys!  I end up dumping the library.

Answer (score 1):

If you end up wanting bootstrap in your react application again, just use `reactstrap` http://reactstrap.github.io/components/modals/